# Applying variable to element jquery

Tags: html, css, variables, jquery-selectors, event-handling

I'm wondering if you can do this in jquery. I'm using version 1.10:

```
var myImage = $('#myImage');
```

What i basically want to do is assign the image as a variable so that i can use it anywhere. I want to use it during event handling:

E.g.

```
myImage.click(function () {
    alert('Image Clicked');
});
```

If the above code is incorrect, I would really like to know the appropriate code.

Comment: did you at least try that code? You would find our that works fine, if it's in the same scoop of where you use the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it. In fact, it is recommended that you assign it to a variable so that you selector is not evaluated each time you use it. It is good for performance reasons.

Finding element by Id (such as in your case `$('#myImage');`) is fast but imagine if you have a selector like

`$('ul > li.myClass:has(p) a:eq(2)')`

Using a variable will speed things up for you in such scenarios.

I usually use `$` sign in variable name like. `var $varName = $('.selector')` It helps me better understand the code and to distinguish between regular variables and variables that contain DOM elements.